# Error declaring types with Google Places API for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Basically I get the error "Type 'GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter' has no member 'food' with the following chunk:

```
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .food
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

According to [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), the type food should be recognized. Any help would be appreciated. Also I apologize if I'm lacking something basic - I'm new to Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this types in **Nearby Search Requests** and when adding a **place** as is show in your link

> Table 1: Types supported in place search and addition
>
> You can use the following values in the types filter for place
>   searches and when adding a place.

not as `GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter`, those are the values can be used in GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter type, I think in your case must use `establishment`

```
/**
 * The type filters that may be applied to an autocomplete request to restrict results to different
 * types.
 */
public enum GMSPlacesAutocompleteTypeFilter : Int {


    /**
     * All results.
     */
    case noFilter

    /**
     * Geeocoding results, as opposed to business results.
     */
    case geocode

    /**
     * Geocoding results with a precise address.
     */
    case address

    /**
     * Business results.
     */
    case establishment

    /**
     * Results that match the following types:
     * "locality",
     * "sublocality"
     * "postal_code",
     * "country",
     * "administrative_area_level_1",
     * "administrative_area_level_2"
     */
    case region

    /**
     * Results that match the following types:
     * "locality",
     * "administrative_area_level_3"
     */
    case city
}
```

Hope this helps you